# How to extract the iid(s) of all the visible top-level items in a ttk.Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

In the root window, I created a `ttk.Treeview` with vertical and horizontal `ttk.Scrollbar`, respectively, within it. What I like to do next is to be able to extract the `iid` of all the visible top-level items, i.e. the iid of Restaurant 0, 1, 2, etc.. whenever I press the `Show Visible Top Level Item iid`. **May I know what is the best way to achieve this objective?**

I experimented using [@JRiggles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76566372/5722359) answer but found that the returned values are not exact. For example, after adjusting the root window to only show:

[image: picture]

the self.show() method returns:

```
total_items=10 treeview_top_level_iids=('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
y_top=0.3333333333333333 y_bottom=0.6
first_visible=3 last_visible=6
visible_tl_idds=['G3', 'G4', 'G5', 'G6']
```

The values of `visible_tl_idds` should have been just `['G4', 'G5']`.

I have tried revising the `self.show()` method algorithm to use:

```
if y_top == 0.0:
    first_visible = 0
else:
    first_visible = int(y_top * total_items) + 1
if y_bottom != 1.0:
    last_visible = int(y_bottom * total_items)
else:
    last_visible = total_items - 1
```

instead of:

```
first_visible = int(y_top * total_items)
last_visible = int(y_bottom * total_items)
```

The result is closer to reality but still not exact. `G6` should not be there.

```
total_items=10 treeview_top_level_iids=('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
y_top=0.3333333333333333 y_bottom=0.6
first_visible=4 last_visible=6
visible_tl_idds=['G4', 'G5', 'G6']
```

**Test script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk as ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        BG0 = '#aabfe0' #Blue scheme
        BG1 = '#4e88e5' #Blue scheme

        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, style='App.TFrame', borderwidth=0,
                           relief='raised', width=390, height=390)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title('Treeview')
        self.parent.geometry('470x350')
        
        self.setStyle()
        self.createWidgets(BG0, BG1)
        
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def setStyle(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('App.TFrame', background='pink')


    def createWidgets(self, BG0, BG1):
        # Treeview with scroll bars
        columns = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(10)]
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self, height=20, selectmode='extended', takefocus=True,
            columns=("type", "property A", "property B", "selected"),
            displaycolumns=["property A", "property B", "selected"])
        self.ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set,
                            xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky='ns')
        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='ew')

        self.tree.column('#0', stretch=True, anchor='w', width=100)
        self.tree.column('property A', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)
        self.tree.column('property B', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)
        self.tree.column('selected', stretch=True, anchor='n', width=100)

        self.tree.heading('#0', text="Type", anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('property A', text='Property A', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('property B', text='Property B', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('selected', text='Selected', anchor='center')

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.tag_configure(i)
            self.tree.insert("", "end", iid=f"G{i}", open=True,
                         tags=[i, 'Parent'], text=f"Restaurant {i}")
            self.tree.insert(f"G{i}", "end", iid=f"C-{i}", text=f"Cookie", 
                         tags=[f"{i}-a", 'Child', "Not Selected"],
                         values=(f"C-{i}-a", f"{i}-Ca", f"{i}-Cb", False))
            self.tree.insert(f"G{i}", "end", iid=f"P-{i}", text=f"Pudding", 
                         tags=[f"P-{i}", 'Child', "Not Selected"],
                         values=(f"P-{i}", f"{i}-Pa", f"{i}-Pb", False))
            
        # Button
        self.showbutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Show Visible Top-Level Items iid", command=self._show)
        self.showbutton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')


    def _show(self):
        self.update_idletasks()
        treeview_top_level_iids = self.tree.get_children()
        total_items = len(treeview_top_level_iids)
        y_top, y_bottom = self.tree.yview()
        first_visible = int(y_top * total_items)
        last_visible = int(y_bottom * total_items)
        # My modifications
        # if y_top == 0.0:
        #    first_visible = 0
        # else:
        #    first_visible = int(y_top * total_items) + 1
        # if y_bottom != 1.0:
        #    last_visible = int(y_bottom * total_items)
        # else:
        #    last_visible = total_items - 1
        visible_tl_idds = [f"G{i}" for i in range(first_visible,
                                                  last_visible + 1)]
        print( f"{total_items=} {treeview_top_level_iids=}")
        print( f"{y_top=} {y_bottom=}")
        print( f"{first_visible=} {last_visible=}")
        print(f"{visible_tl_idds=}")

               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting further, I believe the concise answer to my question is to use the `.get_children()` and `.bbox()` methods of the `ttk.Treeview` widget. The below method should replace the `._show()` method in my question:

```
def _show_visible_toplevel_iids(self):
    self.update_idletasks()
    all_toplevel_iids = self.tree.get_children()
    visible_toplevel_iids = [i for i in all_toplevel_iids
                             if isinstance(self.tree.bbox(i), tuple)]
    
    print()
    print(f"{all_toplevel_iids=}")
    print(f"{visible_toplevel_iids=}")
```

That said, for the same window size given in my question, my answer returns

```
visible_toplevel_iids=['G4', 'G5', 'G6']
```

which is the same answer returned by [@JRiggles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76566372/5722359) answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this in the past - it should be transferrable to you use case.

```
total_items = len(self.tree.get_children())  # get the total no. of items in the tree
y_top, y_bottom = self.tree.yview()  # get the extents of the current view
first_visible = int(y_top * total_items)
last_visible = int(y_bottom * total_items)
```

here, `first_visible` and `last_visible` will return integer values which (unless you've done something different with your item IDs) should be the same as the `iid`s, or at least close enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Your approach works for a treeview widget. However, it does not work when the treeview widget is in the vertical scroll frame widget. For example when the window is resized by moving the base of the window to just covering `Restaurant 3`, it will still show `first_visible=0` `last_visible=6` and not `last_visible=2`. More importantly, I think the morale of the story is that there is no need to put a `ttk.Treeview` widget in a vertical scroll frame given that the `ttk.Treeview` widget has scroll functionality when attached with scroll bars.

Comment: I discovered that your approach assumes a uniform distribution of the top-level items within the treeview hence proportional to the extent returned by `self.tree.yview()`. However, it will not work when some top-level items have more children items.  Furthermore, when the window size of the treeview is reduced to show only one top-level item, the returned idd is incorrect (out by one).